# How to Access to a Local sent JSON in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I am trying to get access to a locally saved .json file which I want to loop through afterward.
Here is the gutscheinDB.json File:

```
{
"gutscheinData": [
    {  "qrCode": "Esteban Gutierez",
        "startDate": "01.01.2016",
        "expireDate": "01.01.2020",
        "JsBarcode": "2345532342324",
        "text": "Gutschein für Autowäsche",
        "value": "5€"
    }, 
    {
        "qrCode": "Ronaldo Keita",
        "startDate": "01.01.2017",
        "expireDate": "01.01.2025",
        "JsBarcode": "2345532342888",
        "text": "Gutschein für Tanken",
        "value": "50€"
    }

]



}
```

Here is the gutschein.js File:

```
var gutscheine=[];

function loadJSON(callback) {
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
 xobj.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/src/js/gutscheinDB.Json', true);
 xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
  callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
}
};
 xobj.send(null);
}
loadJSON(function (json) {
   console.log(json); // this will log out the json object
  gutscheine.push(json);
 });
```

I would then like to loop through the gutschein Array

```
 for (var i in gutscheine.gutscheinData) { 

for (gutscheine.gutscheinData[i] in gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].qrCode) {

var j =gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].qrCode; 
console.log(j);
 }
 i ++;
}
```

I tried and deleted many variants that I found on StackOverflow and w3 but nothing works.
I can´t access the QR code of each object.
In the Chrome Console, I can see the >[] Array with all values and the jsonObject with all values but I can´t Access them like:

```
   gutscheine.gutscheinData[0].qrCode;
```

Comment: `gutscheine` is an array, you're pushing the whole object to it for some reason, so to access _something_ you'd have to do `gutscheine[0].gutscheinData[0].qrCode;`

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/").

Comment: unless you are running this on server you will not able to load the file

Comment: So, what is your current problem? This doesn't seem to be described in your question

Comment: @George  get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' when i try this

Comment: @brk the file get´s loaded because the browser shows the `loadJSON(function (json)`

Comment: @Icepickle I can not access the array... any key or value. it´s allways undefined

Comment: @CueneytSilolGiaccommander did u get your answere or you need help ?

Comment: @shajji no really helpful. @JO3-W3B-D3V made me think about the timing of the callback and the console.log attempt... if i do this:`loadJSON(function (vouchers) {
  console.log(vouchers); // this will log out the json object
  gutscheine=vouchers;
  console.log(gutscheine.gutscheinData[0].qrCode);
}); `   ... it works suddenly and I get **Esteban Gutierez**

Comment: @CueneytSilolGiaccommander yeah it works, bcoz u use `gutscheine = vouchers;` instead of pushing in **gutscheine** array `gutscheine.push(vouchers);` that's why it works suddenly. so if you use `gutscheine.push(vouchers);` u will get your desired value as @George said in first comment `gutscheine[0].gutscheinData[0].qrCode;`. hope this will clear your confusion and if u had any other query please ask.

Answer (score 0):

## Explained

For the sake of simplicity, I decided to use a function that just uses some callback, to simply simulate the `ajax` call, nothing too complicated there.

As you can see, to reduce the number of side effects within the code, I've used `map`, and for the sake of simplicity, I've also used a `forEach` function in the `handlObject` function. If you'd like to further reduce the number of side effects, you could look at using something like `reduce`, etc.

You can clearly see that in this solution, it contains some function to request the data, loop over the data, handle each individual object and some function that will run once everything else has finished, aka `onComplete`.

#### Edit

The reason why your code doesn't work is down to a couple of facts, one being down to the simple fact that you're meant to use a `for (... in...)` loop on an object, to iterate over an objects properties. When you try to do this on an array, you **will**  not get the desired behaviour, instead you need to use a traditional for loop, or like what I've done with a `forEach` or `map` approach.

You'd want to use `forEach` over `map` if side effects aren't anything for you to worry about, but IMO having code with no side effects is pretty neat, hence my style of implementation.

So as @George has mentioned in the comments, you'd want to access object properties via using the index of 0 as `gutscheine` is an array with only one index. Then you can access `gutscheinData` like so:

`gutscheine[0].gutscheinData[0].qrCode;`

If you dislike that syntax, you could always set it up so that `gutscheine` is an object and not an array, that will eliminate the need to use the above syntax, etc.

```js
// Simulate ajax request.
const getData = callback => {
  const data = {
    "gutscheinData": [{
        "qrCode": "Esteban Gutierez",
        "startDate": "01.01.2016",
        "expireDate": "01.01.2020",
        "JsBarcode": "2345532342324",
        "text": "Gutschein für Autowäsche",
        "value": "5€"
      },
      {
        "qrCode": "Ronaldo Keita",
        "startDate": "01.01.2017",
        "expireDate": "01.01.2025",
        "JsBarcode": "2345532342888",
        "text": "Gutschein für Tanken",
        "value": "50€"
      }
    ]
  };

  if (typeof callback == 'function') {
    return callback(data);
  } else {
    return data;
  }
};

// Handle each object.
const handleObject = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(key, obj[key]));

  // Do something, this just returns the value and text properties. 
  const copy = { ...obj};
  return { value: copy.value, text: copy.text };
};

// Just a function to run at the end of everything. 
const onComplete = data => {
  console.log(data);
};

// A simple function to generate an 
// array from the data object's 'gutscheinData' property, then
// pass 'z' array into the 'onComplete' function 
const loop = data => onComplete(data.gutscheinData.map(obj => handleObject(obj)));

// Start the functionality. 
getData(loop);
```

Comment: oh I see it´s a mather of timing... so  I am trying to console.log while callback is not ready, right??

Comment: @CueneytSilolGiaccommander No, I've said in my answer above, you're using the wrong kind of loop, and as George showed you, you need to use index 0 in your original approach, but if you use a similar approach to what I've implemented, you won't need to do anything like that.

Comment: @CueneytSilolGiaccommander Is it all starting to make a little bit more sense?

Comment: wish it would make sense to me... I really do... the way u simulate the request and use the objects looks impressive but I am new to JS and never used ES6. I saw on your profile that u work with PWA´s too. **I need to work it through**. I'll let you know when I got it... thx

Comment: ES6 is easy, may take you some time to get used to, but it's nothing mind blowing, I assure you! :) ... I remember the first time I saw an ```'arrow function'```, I wasn't sure if I liked it or not, now I can't help myself, it's just less to type than ```var x = function()...```, I'm sure you'll get it sooner or later! :) If you like I can write a more traditional style implementation... As for how I handled the request, that's just using callbacks! :)

Answer (score 0):

ok here is what I did to make it work... (guess this is a very noobish approach)

```
var gutscheine;

function loadJSON(callback) {
 var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
 xobj.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/src/js/gutscheinDB.Json', true);
 xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
  callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
}
 };
 xobj.send(null);
}
loadJSON(function (vouchers) {
 console.log(vouchers); // this will log out the json object
 gutscheine=vouchers;
 console.log(gutscheine.gutscheinData[0].qrCode);
 var cardQr=gutscheine.gutscheinData[0].qrCode;
 console.log(cardQr);
 for(var i = 0;i < gutscheine.gutscheinData.length;i++){
 var cardQrcode = gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].qrCode;
  var cardStartDate = gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].startDate;
  var cardExpireDate = gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].expireDate;
 var cardJSBarcode = gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].JsBarcode;
  var cardText = gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].text;
  var cardValue = gutscheine.gutscheinData[i].value; 



console.log(cardQrcode+cardStartDate+cardExpireDate+
   cardJSBarcode+cardText+cardText+cardValue);
     }
     });
```

result:

### Ronaldo Keita01.01.201701.01.20252345532342888Gutschein für TankenGutschein für Tanken50€